# Formatting HTML Table in Power Automate

Tags: sharepoint, html-table, format, sendmail, power-automate

I have a requirement in Power Automate where I want to format HTML table and color the particular cell's items based on choices we made.

Scenario:
I have a SharePoint List that has a choice column and I wanted to reflect that column's items based on values selected with different colors. Then send the email where it is in HTML table.

But in my case, I get the output as show below.
[image: Format HTML Table]

In the Compose action I have used this expression:

```
<style>
  table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
  }

  th, td {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
  }

  th.joining-date {
    background-color: #add8e6;
  }

  td.job-post-date {
    color: yellow;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
</style>
```

Can someone please help me out to resolve this? Thanks in advance!

I want out like this
[image]

Comment: How are you generating the table itself? Update the question with a snip of the action that is building the HTML table.